# find the repetition of duplicate numbers

Tags: data-structures

this is my algorithm that I have written it with my friends (which are in stackoverflow site)
this algorithm will find just the first duplicate number and returns it.this works in `O(n)`
I want to complete this algorithm that helps me to get duplicate numbers with their repetition. consider that I have `[1,1,3,0,5,1,5]`
I want this algorithm to return `2` duplicate numbers which are `1 and 5` with their repetition which is `3 and 2` respectively .how can I do this with `O(n)`?

```
1   Algorithm Duplicate(arr[1:n],n)
2   
3   {
4      Set s = new HashSet();i:=0;
5      while i<a.size() do
6      {
7          if(!s.add(a[i)) then
8          {
9             return a[i]; //this is a duplicate value!
10            break;
11         }
12         i++;
13      } 
14   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Java:

```
List<Integer> num=Arrays.asList(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5);
    Map<Integer,Integer> countNum=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int n:num)
    {
        Integer nu;
        if((nu=countNum.get(n))==null)
        {
            countNum.put(n,1);
            continue;
        }
        countNum.put(n,nu+1);
    }
```

Instead of iterating each time to get count of duplicate it's better to store the count in map.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a Map/Dictionary data structure.
2. Iterate over the list.
3. For each item in list, do a map lookup. If the key (item) exists, increment its value. If the key doesn't exist, insert the key and initial count.

Comment: can you write your algorithm really it is hard for me to get,I am beginner in algorithm thanks in advance

Comment: @user472221: Mutable `Map` and `Dictionary` data structures usually have amortized worst case step complexity of `Θ(1)` for insertion, deletion and lookup. So, the total amortized worst case step complexity of @suihock's suggestion will be `Θ(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular instance it's not so much about the algorithm, it's about the data structure: a `Multiset` is like a `Set`, except it doesn't store only unique items, instead it stores a count of how often each item is in the `Multiset`. Basically, a `Set` tells you whether a particular item is in the `Set` *at all*, a `Multiset` in addition also tells you *how often* that particular item is in the `Multiset`.

So, basically all you have to do is to construct a `Multiset` from your `Array`. Here's an example in Ruby:

```
require 'multiset'

print Multiset[1,1,3,0,5,1,5]
```

Yes, that's all there is to it. This prints:

```
#3 1
#1 3
#1 0
#2 5
```

If you only want actual duplicates, you simply `delete` those items with a count less than `2`:

```
print Multiset[1,1,3,0,5,1,5].delete_with {|item, count| count < 2 }
```

This prints just

```
#1 3
#2 5
```

As @suihock mentions, you can also use a `Map`, which basically just means that instead of the `Multiset` taking care of the element counting for you, you have to do it yourself:

```
m = [1,1,3,0,5,1,5].reduce(Hash.new(0)) {|map, item| map.tap { map[item] += 1 }}
print m
# { 1 => 3, 3 => 1, 0 => 1, 5 => 2 }
```

Again, if you only want the duplicates:

```
print m.select {|item, count| count > 1 }
# { 1 => 3, 5 => 2 }
```

But you can have that easier if instead of counting yourself, you use `Enumerable#group_by` to group the elements by themselves and then map the groupings to their sizes. Lastly, convert back to a `Hash`:

```
print Hash[[1,1,3,0,5,1,5].group_by(&->x{x}).map {|n, ns| [n, ns.size] }]
# { 1 => 3, 3 => 1, 0 => 1, 5 => 2 }
```

All of these have an amortized worst case step complexity of Θ(n).